# Android: Is there a method for after-notification-is-sent?

Tags: android

Trying to implement a snooze functionality on notification.  (Correct me if I'm wrong) So I think one of the ways is to modify the alarm manager when the notification is triggered. So anyone knows if there is a method that's called when the notification is called? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So anyone knows if there is a method that's called when the notification is called?

I have no idea what you consider "the notification is called" to be.

You provide a `PendingIntent` to the `Notification` that will be invoked when the user taps on the `Notification` in the notification drawer. Usually, that `PendingIntent` will point to your code: activity, service, or `BroadcastReceiver`.

For Android 4.1 and higher, you can also have a "big" `Notification` style that has its own buttons, and you can tie a `PendingIntent` to each button.

Hence, on Android 4.1 and higher, I would expect "snooze" to be one of these action buttons, and you could use a broadcast `PendingIntent` to get control and make your changes to your alarm schedule. On Android 4.0 and earlier, "snooze" would be part of the activity that would come up when the user taps on the `Notification`, and you can adjust your alarm schedule at that point.

Comment: I was asking if there is an onCreate method for notification. But I guess I was thinking it wrong. Should create PendingIntent.